# Accessing results of nested tasks from the parent task

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task

I am currently exploring TPL and i am wondering if the following scenario is possible:

I'd like to create a nested structure with a single parent and multiple "child" tasks under it.

The structure is similar to this:

```
Parent Task
    |
    |-- Child Task A
    |-- Child Task B 
    |-- ...
```

I would like the parent task to wait for all child tasks to complete, and access their results (in order to determine the result of itself).

I could not find any valuable information of nesting tasks and accessing their result from the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use the static method [`Task.WaitAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall.aspx) in the parent-task to wait for all child tasks to complete, then check their individual `Status`- and `Result`-properties.

If there is no work at all for the parent-task before all child-tasks are completed, you could restructure it and use [`TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321258.aspx) to start a new task once all child-tasks are completed. This can then access the individual results.

Comment: You can still use `ContinueWhenAll()` even if there is some more work in the parent Task.

Comment: Task.WaitAll is equivalent to Parallel.Invoke in this scenario. Both waste the parent task's thread by blocking. Better to use ContinueWhenAll to avoid unnecessary blocking.

Comment: I would like to (somehow) construct a tree-like Task object that will simply be able to Start() and will do its thing. This sounds like i will need to do it differently...